# When is getters setters needed in android studio project?

Tags: java, android, setter, jdeveloper, getter

I can generate getters and setters in java program and I know that it is used to access private variables. Besides this How will I be able to decide this, at this point I need to create java class with getters and setters.

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: I just wanted to know that how will I be able to realize that" Ok, now I have to make a java class with getters and setters." I'm just confused in this.

Comment: @Nilesh when you want to represent an Entity you have to make a Java class with private fields and public setter/getter methods to access outside that class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use getters and setters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getter and Setter methods are used for `encapsulate` the data.
it means wrapping the data into single unit.

For example create a `ListView` with 3 `TextView` who has different-different value.

so now the question is how will you send the data to your custom `ListView` adapter. In this case you have to use a beam(has getter-setter methods) class.

## EDIT:

Here is another example it will show how to send multiple data by single object from one Activity to another Activity

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7827593/6676466

Comment: Will you give me few more examples?

Answer (score 0):

in modern java programming you must importantly follow **information**

hiding this is making the class fields to become `private` or

`protected`(to be used by child class) that is why we have getter and setter

method, also **getter** and **setter** is useful when you want to have a range check in each data field

if you want to directly access the variable you can create a child class of that parent class and set each fields to become `protected`